# list the unicode array separately in template in python

Tags: python, django, unicode, datefield

The Following is my view.py

```
def UpdatePage(request):
    templatevar = {}
    user_name = request.session['login_user_email']
    update_form = Update_Page()
    if user_name:
        home_page_form = Home_Page
        templatevar['varobj']=models.ProfileDetail.objects.filter(email=user_name)
        if request.method=='POST':
        update_name=request.POST['name']
        update_age=request.POST['age']
        update_gender=request.POST.get('gender')
        update_interested_in=request.POST.getlist('interested_in')
        for i in update_interested_in:
            print i
        update_dob=request.POST.get('dob')
        update_country=request.POST['country']
        update_about_you=request.POST['about_you']
        update_profile_detail=models.ProfileDetail.objects.filter(email=user_name).update(name=update_name,age=update_age,gender=update_gender,
        interested_in=update_interested_in,dob=update_dob,country=update_country,about_you=update_about_you)
        if update_profile_detail:
            details_updated="Your Profile Details are Updated"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('homepage',{'details_updated':details_updated})
return render(request,'update.html',{'user_name':user_name,'update_form':update_form,'templatevar':templatevar})
```

The Following is my Template View

```
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Update Here</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
<h3 style="text-align:right"><div><a href="homepage">Home</a></div><div><a href="logout">Log Out</a></div></h3>
{{user_name}}
    <h3>Update Here</h3>
    <!--{{update_form.as_p}}-->
    {% for all in templatevar.varobj %}
        <p>Age:{{all.age}}<br></p>
        <p>Gender:{{all.gender}}<br></p>
        <p>Interested In:{{all.interested_in}}<br></p>
        {%for i in all.interested_in%}
        {{i}}
        {%endfor%}
        <p>DOB:{{all.dob}}<br></p>
        <p>Country:{{all.country}}<br></p>
        <p>About You:{{all.about_you}}<br></p>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for all in templatevar.varobj %}
<p><label for="id_name">People Call You As:</label> <input id="id_name" name="name" type="text" value="{{all.name}}" /></p>
<p><label for="id_email">Your Email:</label> <input id="id_email" name="email" type="email" value="{{user_name}}" readonly /></p>
<p><label for="id_age">Age:</label> <input id="id_age" name="age" type="number"value="{{all.age}}" /></p>
<p><label for="id_gender_0">Gender:</label> <ul id="id_gender">
<li><label for="id_gender_0"><input id="id_gender_0" name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" {% if all.gender == "Male" %}checked="checked"{% endif %} /> Male</label></li>
<li><label for="id_gender_1"><input id="id_gender_1" name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" {% if all.gender == "Female" %}checked="checked"{% endif %} /> Female</label></li>
```

```
<p><label for="id_interested_in_0">Interested In:</label>
<ul id="id_interested_in">
<li><label for="id_interested_in_0">
<input id="id_interested_in_0" name="interested_in" type="checkbox"     value="Sports" {% if all.interested_in == "Sports" %}checked="checked"{% endif %}/> Sports</label></li>
<li><label for="id_interested_in_1"><input id="id_interested_in_1" name="interested_in" type="checkbox" value="Music" {% if all.interested_in == "Music" %}checked="checked"{% endif %} /> Music</label></li>
<li><label for="id_interested_in_2"><input id="id_interested_in_2" name="interested_in" type="checkbox" value="Gardening" {% if all.interested == "Gardening" %}checked="checked"{% endif %}/> Gardening</label></li>
```

```
<p><label for="id_dob">Date Of Birth:</label> <input id="id_dob" name="dob" type="text" value="{{all.dob}}" placeholder = "YYYY-MM-DD" /></p>
<p><label for="id_country">Your From:</label> <select id="id_country" maxlength="3" name="country">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="America">America</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="id_about_you">About You:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_about_you" name="about_you" rows="10" value="">{{all.about_you}}
</textarea></p>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is my model view:

```
class ProfileDetail(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,unique=True,null=True)
age = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
interested_in = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
dob = models.DateField(null=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True)
about_you = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.interested_in
```

I need to display the check box value separately as
Sports
Music
Gardening
and not the following
Interested In:[u'Sports', u'Music', u'Gardening']
How to display separately and check the values

Comment: Could you show forms.py? If Sports, Music and Gardening are the standard choices, you should use a ChoiceField. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

Comment: I did not display my form in form in forms.py.. i just directly displayed in html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to store a list into a char field, that's why you are seeing the `repr` of the list.

First, in your view, change the line:

```
update_interested_in=request.POST.getlist('interested_in')
```

to

```
update_interested_in = ','.join(request.POST.getlist('interested_in'))
```

Then add a method to your `model.py` that splits the string:

```
class ProfileDetail(models.Model):
    ...
    def interested_in_list(self):
        return self.interested_in.split(',')
```

You can then use the `join` template filter:

```
{{ all.interested_in_list|join:"<br/>"|safe }}
```

If you have to construct the checkboxes yourself, you can use something like:

```
{% for interest in all.interested_in_list %}
<input name="interested_in" type="checkbox" value="{{ interest }}"> {{ interest }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if i use as like above i am only getting spaces in between the letters ........ I need to display in line by line and should store the Sports,Music,Gardening in each variable.

Comment: `{{ all.interested_in|join:" -" }}`......results in .......Interested In : [-u-'-S-p-o-r-t-s-'-,- -u-'-M-u-s-i-c-'-,- -u-'-G-a-r-d-e-n-i-n-g-'-] and by the way the second option by giving break displays each letter. When i give the wordcount of array it displays 3........ i need to store them in each variable to assign it in check box.... if possible to call by array kindly help me. I am new to python

Comment: I see, you don't have a list but a string representation of a list then. Try my updated answer.

Comment: ya its a string representation of list... it considers each characters not the word, and your updated answer again does'nt work for me. :(... again it displays each letters

Comment: Did you add the `interested_in_list` method as I described? And this will only work with records you created _after_ you made changes, because the old values in the database are incorrect.

Comment: yeah it works :) and how can i access the list of each word and assign to the checkbox ??

Comment: Well, you can loop over the list and construct your checkboxes. See updated answer.

Comment: well, but i dont want to construct the checkbox.. i need to just display the value as checked which was already constructed.. kindly view my template view. i have constructed the checkbox already. Is there any way to check the values over there ??

Comment: Yes, just change your existing logic to `{% if "Music" in all.interested_in_list %}checked="checked"...` etc.